# Python copy file from remote machine to local machine

Tags: python

I want to copy file from remote machine (Ex: 1.1.1.1) present in some directory to my local machine.

Please let me know how to do it. If you can put any example that would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

I am using windows machine remote as well as local.

Comment: which platform ? linux ?

Comment: You will not get an answer unless you provide more detail. Which platform is the remote system? Which platform is the local system? What kind of file sharing service does the remote system run (Windows file sharing, NFS, ssh, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

The tool I use for copying to/from remote machines is [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.2/index.html).

Comment: Sorry for not providing the proper data. I am using windows machine remote as well as local.

Comment: For googlers: fabric currently only works in python 2.x but paramiko works in python 3

Answer (score 1):

Set up password less SSH between the 2 machines and do unlimited file transfers.. or use pexpect module to enter password when asked in your script

Comment: I'd rather suggest using http://www.lag.net/paramiko/ for this. It does support sftp, too.

Comment: paramiko would also work fine..